# What are the problems with the fuzzy system?

Tags: r, fuzzy-logic

So I have this code which creates a rule based fuzzy system:

```
install.packages("sets")
library(sets)
sets_options("universe", seq(1,100,0.5))

variables<-set(
  temperature=fuzzy_partition(varnames=c(cold=30, 
                                         good=70, hot=90), sd=5),
  humidity=fuzzy_partition(varnames=c(dry=30, good=60, wet=80), sd=3),
  precipitations=fuzzy_partition(varnames=c(no.rain=30, 
                                          little.rain=60, rain=90), sd=7.5),
  weather=fuzzy_partition(varnames=c(bad=40, ok=65, perfect=80), FUN=fuzzy_cone,
                        radius=10)
)

rules<-set(
  fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% good && humidity %is% dry &&
               precipitations %is% no.rain , weather %is% perfect),
  fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% hot && humidity %is% wet &&
               precipitations %is% rain, weather %is% bad),
  fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% cold && weather %is% bad),
  fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% good || humidity %is% good || precipitations %is%
               little.rain, weather %is%ok),
  fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% hot && precipitations %is% little.rain , weather %is% ok),
  fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% hot && humidity %is% dry  
             &&precipitations %is% little.rain, weather %is% ok))

model<-fuzzy_system(variables, rules)
plot(model)


example<-fuzzy_inference(model,list(temperature=65,
                             humidity=0, precipitations=80)) //here is the error 
plot(example)
```

The error is this : " Error in `[[<-`(i$consequent, 1L, as.name("$")) : 
  object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable " and I don't know what this means.

Comment: I find one of the cases is producing `numeric(0)` which changes it to a `list` and resulting in error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues in the OP's 'rules'

```
library(sets)
as.list(rules)
#[[1]]
#temperature %is% hot && precipitations %is% little.rain => weather %is% ok

#[[2]]
#Error in format.default(x$consequent) : 
#  Found no format() method for class "name"
```

Basically, the third rule doesn't have a value

```
...
fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% cold && weather %is% bad),  ### 
...
```

Another problem is the 'variables' created with `fuzzy_cone` 'radius' not overlapping creating a NULL set

```
variables
#{weather = (bad = {}, ok = {}, perfect = {}), humidity = (dry = <<gset(201)>>, good = <<gset(201)>>, wet = <<gset(201)>>),
#temperature = (cold = <<gset(201)>>, good = <<gset(201)>>, hot = <<gset(201)>>), precipitations = (no.rain = <<gset(201)>>,
#little.rain = <<gset(201)>>, rain = <<gset(201)>>)}
```

---

If we do the necessary changes, it would work

```
variables<-set(
      temperature=
         fuzzy_partition(varnames=
                     c(cold=30, good=70, hot=90), 
                     sd=5),
       humidity=
          fuzzy_partition(varnames=
               c(dry=30, good=60, wet=80), 
               sd=3),
       precipitations=
              fuzzy_partition(varnames=
                      c(no.rain=30, little.rain =60, rain=90), sd=7.5),
      weather=fuzzy_partition(varnames=c(bad=40, ok=65, perfect=80), FUN=fuzzy_cone,
                            radius=75)
    )


rules<-set(
               fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% good && humidity %is% dry && precipitations %is% no.rain , 
                        weather %is% perfect),
               fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% hot && humidity %is% wet &&  precipitations %is% rain, 
                 weather %is% bad),
               fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% cold,
                   weather %is% bad),           
              fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% good || humidity %is% good || precipitations %is% little.rain,
                   weather %is% ok),
              fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% hot && precipitations %is% little.rain,
                   weather %is% ok),
              fuzzy_rule(temperature %is% hot && humidity %is% dry && precipitations %is% little.rain,
                   weather %is% ok))
```

-check the rules

```
as.list(rules)
#[[1]]
#temperature %is% hot && precipitations %is% little.rain => weather %is% ok

#[[2]]
#temperature %is% hot && humidity %is% dry && precipitations %is%  => weather %is% ok
#    little.rain => weather %is% ok

#[[3]]
#temperature %is% hot && humidity %is% wet && precipitations %is%  => weather %is% bad
#    rain => weather %is% bad

#[[4]]
#temperature %is% good && humidity %is% dry && precipitations %is%  => weather %is% perfect
 #   no.rain => weather %is% perfect

#[[5]]
#temperature %is% good || humidity %is% good || precipitations %is%  => weather %is% ok
 #   little.rain => weather %is% ok

#[[6]]
#temperature %is% cold => weather %is% bad
```

build the `fuzzy_system`

```
model <- fuzzy_system(variables, rules)
example <- fuzzy_inference(model,list(temperature=65,
                                 humidity=0, precipitations=80))
```